# How to change image when it is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following icons where i want to change each of it when it is clicked And change the image to its original after another image is clicked. how do i do it with jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="button" id="mobile-icon" href="#"><img src="images/mobile-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Mobile</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="music-icon" href="#" ><img src="images/music-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Music</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="camera-icon" href="#" ><img  src="images/camera-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Camera</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="computers-icon" href="#" ><img  src="images/computers-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Computers</h4></li>
</ul>
```

I only code the jquery this far.. and I am stuck. please help..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.clicked').removeClass("clicked")
        $(this).addClass("clicked")
        if ($(".button").hasClass("clicked")) {
            var id = $(this).find('img');
            var idToSRC = 'images/'+ this.id + '_hover' +'.png';
            id.attr('src', idToSRC);
        }else if($(".button").not("clicked")){
            id.removeAttr('src', idToSRC);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function(){
      var myid = $(this);
      $('.clicked').removeClass("clicked")
      myid.addClass("clicked")
      var idToSRC = 'images/'+ this.id + '_hover' +'.png';
      myid.find('img').attr('src', idToSRC);
      $('.button').not(myid).each(function(){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/'+ this.id +'.png');
      });
  });
});//missed
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {// when document is ready
  $('.button').click(function(){ // when i click on a link
      var myid = $(this); // create an object variable
      $('.clicked').removeClass("clicked") //remove clicked class from all links
      myid.addClass("clicked") //add clicked class to current clicked link
      var idToSRC = 'images/'+ this.id + '_hover' +'.png'; //create new image path
      myid.find('img').attr('src', idToSRC); // change image path of current clicked link
      $('.button').not(myid).each(function(){ //for each other links except the current clicked link (not(myid) is doing that job to leave current clicked link)
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/'+ this.id +'.png'); //change images to orignal-one
      });
  });
});// you missed this in your code
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a class="button" id="mobile-icon" href="#"><img src="images/mobile-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Mobile</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="music-icon" href="#" ><img src="images/music-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Music</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="camera-icon" href="#" ><img  src="images/camera-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Camera</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="computers-icon" href="#" ><img  src="images/computers-icon.png" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Computers</h4></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi sorry i think i mis-wrote my question, how do i change the image to its original after another image is clicked?

Comment: @Untitled Added explanation in comments

Comment: @Untitled  glad to help you mate :):):)

Answer (score 2):

You Button `click` has not been close seems like some syntax error overall code is working fine please find below snippet fore more info.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.button').click(function(){
      $('.clicked').removeClass("clicked")
      $(this).addClass("clicked")
      if ($(".button").hasClass("clicked")) 
      {
          var id = $(this).find('img');
          //var idToSRC = 'images/'+ this.id + '_hover' +'.png';
          var idToSRC = 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/';
          id.attr('src', idToSRC);
      }
      else if($(".button").not("clicked"))
      {
        id.removeAttr('src', idToSRC);
      }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a class="button" id="mobile-icon" href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fffg/000" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Mobile</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="music-icon" href="#" ><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fffg/000" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Music</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="camera-icon" href="#" ><img  src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fffg/000" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Camera</h4></li>
    <li><a class="button" id="computers-icon" href="#" ><img  src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fffg/000" class="defaultimg"></a><h4>Computers</h4></li>
</ul>
```